# How to calculate the two tangent points to a circle with radius R from two lines given by three points

Tags: math, geometry, 2d, html5-canvas

This is related to the arc drawn by HTML5 canvas "arcTo" function. I need to calculate the two tangent points of a circle with the radius R and two lines given by three points Q(x0,y0), P(x1,y1) and R(x2,y2).

The sketch explains the problem more. I need to find the tangent points A(xa,ya) and B(xb,yb). Note that the center of the circle is not given. Please help.

[image]

Comment: This is not a well-defined problem.  The circle could be anywhere along the line stretching out from P through its origin.  Also, this seems like pure math, not programming so you should probably ask it on the Math board.

Comment: @MattPhillips HTML5 canvas "arcTo" function draws the arc only at the direction shown by the image I attached. which means, both lines start at the point P(x1,y1) and go to infinity passing other two points. and, if you can show me how to find them in Javascript, that would be really helping.

Comment: Is the idea that the radius of the circle is known in advance?

Comment: @MattPhillips yes the radius R is given.

Answer (score 1):

This is a question of solving a triangle with 2 known angles and one known side.  Label the centre of the circle C, then the side you know is BC (or AC if you want).  Angle PBC (CAP) is a right angle.  The line CP bisects the angle RPQ.

[Not all such triangles have a solution.](http://www.teacherschoice.com.au/Maths_Library/Trigonometry/solve_trig_AAS.htm)

Comment: In this case I think there will be no solution iff P, Q and R are colinear.

Comment: Though I can't imagine an angle that would not allow a bitangent circle of a given radius.